# How to sort python list based on its element that is a tuple at index zero [0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a python list right here

```
my_list = [("ww","hello"),("www","world"),("w","sardines")]
```

So I wanted to sort this list based on the length value of the first index of the tuple element which is as you can see there is the letter `"w"`.  To be more specific the output should be like this

```
my_list = [("w","sardines"),("ww","hello"),("www","world")]
```

I've searched many sorting techniques for this but I find those with for example a string element only. I was thinking of using a sorting algorithm for this like bubble sort, merge sort, insertion or  any other sorting algorithm... but I think I am lost in that part and also I think that there is a better way to do this without even using a sorting algorithm. I feel like there's a simpler way like just calling a `.sort()` function.

Thank you so much for your help! Glad to ask questions here in this great community! Thank you!

Comment: You can also use `sorted(my_list)` to return a sorted list without modifying the original list.

Comment: Hello! yep I tried and it returns None :/

Comment: @Jan Read the documentation for the `.sort()` method and the `sorted()` function. The former does not return anything, it modifies the list itself.

Comment: @darcamo OMY!! IT WORKED! Thank you! I did not know it was possible like that! I mean woow! 

However may I ask cause I've been reading about the prons and cons on using the .sort() function and sorted() function cause sometimes it might not gives the output that we expect. Do you think it would sort correctly any sentence based on its length?

Comment: @Jan Be careful: Your example is not a very good one as the alphabetical ordering and the length ordering are the same. See dimay's answer below for comparing the lengths.

Comment: the sorted() worked :) cool! The thing is here I am trying to sort a sentence like for example "The sheep is colored white...." , "My computer isn't powerful". Strings like that so would it sort it correctly? based on the length of that string? Thank you so much! and I'll read the docs! @Selcuk

Comment: My example on the "w" is I think okay cause I just wanted to sort the list based on the length of the first element from the tuple but anyways Thank you! I've read the answers from the other people and all of them are great but I think I am seeing the best one :)

Comment: For a list of strings, the sorting is not based on length. It is based on alphabetical order. The caveat is that case matters and upper case letters come before lower case letters (tip: see the ASCII table to see why). For example, `sorted(["dog", "mouse", "camel", "Zebra", "horse", "duck"])` results in `['Zebra', 'camel', 'dog', 'duck', 'horse', 'mouse']`. Notice how `"Zebra"` comes before everything even though it starts with "Z" and how "camel" comes before "dog" even though it has more characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_list = [("ww","hello"),("www","world"),("w","sardines")]

def take_el(elem):
    return len(elem[0])

sorted(my_list, key=take_el)
```

or with lambda

```
sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: len(x[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help! I'll go for the 

sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: len(x[0]))

Thank you!

Comment: Tho both are just the same right :D the good thing with lambda is it just keeps it short and since it only just does one task. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Use this simple technique to sort on the basis of 1st element in tuple:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
```

Change `x[0]` to `x[1]` to sort the list using the length of 2nd tuple element and so on..

Comment: `sorted()` already returns a list, so the `list()` is unnecessary.

Comment: yep.. changes made

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help!  This is actually I think the answer for my question and I loved it when using lamba cause it keeps the code short... however @dimay answered it first so I think I'll have to check the answer anyways THANK YOU! I'll vote up

Comment: Yes, no problem! Actually he saw my answer and then updated his accordingly but I don't mind as long as the knowledge spreads. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [("ww","hello"),("www","world"),("w","sardines")]
listOrder = []
newList = []
for i in my_list:
    listOrder.append(int(len(i[0])))
listOrder.sort()
for i in listOrder:
    for j in my_list:
        if i == len(j[0]):
            newList.append(j)

print(newList)
```

This will also help.

Comment: The time complexity of for loop is the most. Programming is about finding an efficient solution wherever possible. Your program would take up loads of memory just to sort a simple tuple list

Comment: Yes I agree with you @RaghavGupta, I was trying to create an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help! I'll still consider this depending on my future goals!

Answer (score 0):

use sorted where x is the tuple and x[n] is the slice

```
my_list = [("ww","hello"),("www","world"),("w","sardines")]

result = sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: x[0])
print(result)
```